# linq return single row from a goup

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of rows like this (NULLs since i'm using DefaultIfEmpty)

```
Vol           Component         Dwg      View    Revision   

Volume U01  Composed Drawings   SJTest  1   B
Volume U01  Composed Drawings   SJTest  1   A
Volume U01  Composed Drawings   SJTest  1   NULL
Volume U03  Composed Drawings   SJTest2 2   NULL
```

I want to sort by the last coln, (A,B,NULL) for each group and then get only the first row. So in this case I should have the final set as something like:

```
Volume U01  Composed Drawings   SJTest  1   B
Volume U03  Composed Drawings   SJTest2 2   NULL
```

Any thoughts ? I'm lost on how to get this from the grouping - first row of each group.

This is LINQ-SQL...sorry for forgetting that.

thanks
Sunit

Comment: Is this Linq-to-SQL or in-memory Linq? Can you post a small (relevant) extract of the code you have already so we can use that as a starting point?

Comment: Do you have any code that you could post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you say that the first row of the first group should be revision "B", I'm guessing that you want to sort in descending order, so something like this?

```
var query = yourData
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.Vol, x.Component, x.Dwg, x.View })
            .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Revision).First());

// and to test...
foreach (var x in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}",
        x.Vol, x.Component, x.Dwg, x.View, x.Revision ?? "NULL");
}

// Volume U01    Composed Drawings    SJTest     1    B
// Volume U03    Composed Drawings    SJTest2    2    NULL
```

Comment: This worked with a small edit:
.GroupBy(x=>new {x.Volumne, x.Component, x.Drawing}, x=>x)
.Select(g=>g.First());